# Crypto in NodeJS fails when unicode characters

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

I'm trying to validate data integrity using NodeJS Crypto library. It requires calculating the Hmac of a JSON string.

After some test, I've been able to locate the issue: it happens whenever it contains a unicode character. For instance:

```
var hasher = crypto.createHmac("sha256", 'secret_key');
hasher.write('{"timezone":"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US \u0026 Canada)"}');
hasher.end();

var calculatedHmac = new Buffer(hasher.read(), 'utf8').toString('base64');
console.log(calculatedHmac);
```

However this returns the wrong hmac. The same code in PHP matched the signature I received from the third party service:

```
$data = '{"timezone":"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US \u0026 Canada)"}';

$calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, 'secret_key', true));
var_dump($calculated_hmac); // Result is correct here
```

If I remove the "\u0026" in the NodeJS payload, then I get the same correct result as in PHP.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\uXXXX` escape sequence notation is only supported by PHP from version 7 ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)).

If you're using an older PHP version, these escape sequences will be passed literally (so `\u0026` is a 6-character substring), whereas Node will interpret it as a single character (`&`).

If you want Node to stop interpreting the escape sequence, you need to escape the backslash:

```
hasher.write('{"timezone":"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US \\u0026 Canada)"}');
```

When you do that, the result for Node and PHP will be the same (`0CE0++Kn9mi5xd7nAz/mWOrr7939RWwzfxhBzxAWtAk=` to be exact).

Comment: That was it, thanks! Now I just need to find the way to escape those unicode in NodeJS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but I have a good guess:

You must be facing a charset issue. You explicitly converted your buffer to UTF-8 in node.js. This way you have a hash from a Binary representation of a UTF-8 encoded string.

I bet PHP internally deals with another charset (maybe Unicode), which will provide a different binary representation of your string.

To get things right, you must assure to convert both to same binary representation before hashing.

Update: i just noticed that you hashed string directly and converted hash representation to UTF8. You must invert this behaviour: translate your string to UTF-8 BEFORE hashing. And you must proceed the same in PHP. Both platforms must agree to an encoding before hashing.